# execCommand give error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, execcommand

I create a new iframe then append it to the main window document and execute this javascript:

```
frame.contentDocument.execCommand('insertimage',0,'obama.jpg');
```

Where frame is the iframe element. Unfortunatey I get this error:

```
Error: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.execCommand]
```

How can I enable execCommand() function in an iframe? Is there something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document needs to be editable. This can be done by either of the followin methods:

```
frame.contentDocument.designMode = 'on';           // = 'off'; to disable`
frame.contentDocument.body.contentEditable = true; // = false; to disable`
```

`execCommand` ought to be used for editable elements only. Your error indicates that this is not the case. If you want to insert a new image in the document, just use:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://example.com/obama.jpg';
frame.contentDocument.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: `execCommand()` works on non-editable content in IE but not other browsers. A lot of commands would be useful on non-editable content too. For example, `HiliteColor` can be used to apply a background colour to a selection that may cross element boundaries, so can be used for a custom highlighter for regular content. Currently an ugly workaround is required (switching `designMode` on and off).

Comment: is it true that chrome yet to support image resizing?

Comment: one more question. how can we get the image element if we insert it using execCommand? is there any way to do it? anyway thanx for your help

Comment: @NajibRazak These are two entirely different questions. If you want to get *great* answers to that, I suggest to create a new question (after you've done some research and concluded that you weren't able to find the answer yourself).